# How to pass PreparedStatement setArray for character array

Tags: java, jdbc

I have some JDBC code as follows:

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = ? and PASSWORD = ?";

Integer userId = 1000;
char[] passwordString = new char[] { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);
preparedStatement.setArray(2,... ??? // how to do this part?

// execute select SQL statement
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

How do I call `preparedStatement.setArray` to set the second parameter in the query? I don't want to use a string parameter here to protect the password.

Note I am using Hypersonic DB but plan to move to MySql if this is useful.

Comment: I'm not sure you want to do this.

Comment: Why? I wish to avoid using a `String` as I understand there is a certain security risk having the password in one.

Comment: In this case no problem, there is a problem if you do not use a preparedstatement (sql injection)

Comment: I think a salted and encrypted password would be a much better idea.

Answer (score 9):

[PreparedStatement#setArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray%28int,%20java.sql.Array%29) received a [java.sql.Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html)
First you should use the JDBC Connection's [createArrayOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method to create the array, only then you can pass it to `setArray`.

As the method only accept `Object[]` you should create an array of `Character` instead of char.

For example:

```
Character[] passwordString = new Character[] { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
Array sqlArray = con.createArrayOf("CHAR", passwordString);
preparedStatement.setArray(2, sqlArray);
```

Comment: First you should know that the type in db is an ARRAY

Comment: You need to provide `the SQL name of the type the elements of the array map to` (i.e. the type of the elements not the array itself)

Comment: You did not undestand. Then type of column in dabase should be [Array](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_array). Then you can use `java.sql.Array`. This type allow you to store multiple data in single row, without any additional relation. It was not designed in the way you are trying to imply.

Comment: Ah yes, the column type is ARRAY, what did I imply ?

Comment: It is not common to use this type for storing data as you have preseted as solution.

Comment: I didn't present anything, He asked how to use setArray and I answered

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass an array in prepared statement just call

`preparedStatemtn.setArray(index,array);`

But what you must assure first is that in your DB the column is also a [ARRAY](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_array). For more detail please see Aviram Sagal answer.

---

But your base idead it to protect the password.

This solution will protect only from reading the passoword from Java string pool. This is very ratre type of attact anyway. Ans passoword is transmited as plain text.

My sugestion is that instead of complicating the db schema, you should use some benefits of cryptography. Instaed of passing the password value, you should pass [password digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

A simplyfied example of digest function.

```
public static String getDigest(byte[] password) {

  return new String(Hex.encodeHex(new MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA").digest(password)));

}
```

Then you store in db the digest with is safe and you use simple string in queries.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this code

```
final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT my_column FROM my_table " + 
        "where search_column IN (SELECT * FROM unnest(?))"
);
final String[] values = getValues();
statement.setArray(1, connection.createArrayOf("text", values));
final ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
try {
    while(rs.next()) {
        // do some...
    }
} finally {
    rs.close();
}
```

also please take a look at this article for reference http://people.apache.org/~djd/derby/publishedapi/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: That uses a string and I wish to avoid using a string. Is it possible with an array of `char`?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a [`CharArrayReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/CharArrayReader.html) and call the [`statement.setCharacterStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
char[] passwordString = new char[] { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
statement.setCharacterStream(1, new CharArrayReader(passwordString));
```

Comment: Would this method be suitable for inserting plaintext passwords?

Comment: In theory yes. Just make sure to set to null the references to mark the object as candidate for collection