# How to input an array of ID and values to a stored procedure as a parameter using Java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, procedure, callable-statement

I need to input an **array** of **ID** (which is of NUMERIC type) and **value** (which is of VARCHAR2 type) as a **parameter** to a stored procedure.  The Structure is given below

```
TYPE plan_dtl AS OBJECT(
p_id NUMERIC,
p_value VARCHAR2
);
TYPE plan_tbl AS TABLE OF plan_dtl;
PROCEDURE sp_update(p_name IN OUT VARCHAR2, p_array IN pk_manage.plan_tbl);
```

Can anyone tell me how to set an array of values in the position 2 using java ?

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call package_name.sp_update(?,?)}");  
cs.registerOutParameter(1,Types.CHAR);
cs.setString(1, "some name");  
cs.setArray(2, "how to pass it here ?")
```

sample inputs will be like

id(NUMERIC) value(VARCHAR2)

```
[{88627,"02"},{88671,"01"},{88644,"05"}]
```

all these values should be passed as an array to the callable statement at position 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass PreparedStatement setArray for character array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973212/how-to-pass-preparedstatement-setarray-for-character-array)

Comment: Hi @Jamey I have went through this one already. but my case is different. its not an array of character.   its an array of **id** and **values** where id is a numeric type and value is varchar2 type

Comment: Ah OK, so are you looking for a dictionary method then? I imagine you would have to pass two separate arrays, one for the keys and one for the values. It's a bit outside my expertise though, so hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: Searching about this since a while, have tried with HashMap as a arraylist too, but it doesn't work like that also. Since there is only one parameter in the procedure I think I wont be able to pass two separate arrays

Comment: This is for C#, but I believe the same principals should apply: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957132/pass-dictionarystring-int-to-stored-procedure-t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957132/pass-dictionarystring-int-to-stored-procedure-t-sql). When you say there is only one parameter in the procedure, are you unable to modify the procedure?

Comment: No, I don't have access for modifying the procedure. can you suggest a better way to create the procedure as well ?

Comment: If you don't have access to modify the procedure, do you have a reference to an existing implementation? If you can't modify the procedure, then I assume that's because it's already in use? I'm not sure what you mean by a better way to create the procedure, Are you suggesting creating a new stored procedure to fit your purpose?

Comment: Yea for creating a new stored procedure to fit the purpose. Its a newly created procedure, which is created by another team. I don't have direct access for modifying the procedure, but I can suggest them to change.