# Java sql database login

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am having problem with database, creating a login screen that has 1 choice box, 1 textfield for username, 1 jpasswordfield for password.
Database name-admin(username text,password text)

It's showing an error. How can I fix this.

Here is my code:

```
if(choice.getSelectedIndex()==1)
{
  try {
      String sql ="SELECT password FROM admin WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
      pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setString(1, UserName.getText());
      /*Showing: "The method setString(int, String) in the type
        PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, char[])*/
      pst.setString(2,passwordField.getPassword());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the `char[]` array to a string before passing it to the statement:

```
String sql = "SELECT password FROM admin WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, UserName.getText());
pst.setString(2, new String(passwordField.getPassword()));
```

If you have a look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])), you will see that one of the `String` constructors in fact accepts a `char[]` as the input.

Comment: If the intention is to use `char[]` to prevent the password from ending up in the string pool in JVM's memory, then this solution will void that intention (by creating a new `String`). An alternative solution would be to set a character stream on the statement, as exemplified in [this aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18253662/905488). This of course requires that the JDBC driver doesn't eventually create a `String` out of the array.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Good comment, I have never heard of this concern before.  But there is an even bigger problem apparently, namely that the OP is storing cleartext passwords in the database.  Instead we should be hashing the `char[]` and then passing this to the statement (I think).

Comment: I agree, plaintext passwords in the DB are a much bigger concern in real life scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
pst.setString(2,String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword()));
```

The method getPassword() returns chararray and you need a String.

Best